# How can I update/remove a notification from the notification centre?

Tags: c#, ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin, uilocalnotification

I schedule a local notification to go off 6 minutes from when the user enters a specific geolocation, provided they remain within this location.

This is scheduled like so:

```
UILocalNotification n = new UILocalNotification();
n.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(360);
n.AlertAction = "My notification";
n.AlertBody = "Notification body";    
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(n);
```

In some instances, certain geolocations are overlapping and the user will receive more than one notification. When this occurs I would like to be able to update the notification in the notification centre to reflect this.

I was informed a direct update to the notification centre is not possible in iOS9, so to achieve what I want I would need to remove the notification and replace it with a new one.

From a few hours of googling I found the following methods, all of which did not work.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
```

This function did not appear to do anything in the current version of iOS.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Some mentioned that the badge number must first be set, and then made zero to remove notifications from the notification centre. This also had no effect.

```
foreach(UILocalNotification n in UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(n);
}
```

For some that found that `CancelAllNotifications` didn't work tried the above method. This also seemed to have no effect. If it helps, I tried logging a Count of `ScheduledLocalNotifications` while there were notifications on display in the notification centre, but the array came back empty.

```
List<UILocalNotifications> notifications = new List<UILocalNotifications>();

...

UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(n);
notifications.Add(n);

...

foreach(UILocalNotification n in notifications)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(n);
}
```

Another user suggested holding onto the original notifications and then using those to cancel them when needed to later. Again I had no luck with this.

Answers in Objective-C or Swift would also be much appreciated, I can comprehend either of these languages.

Comment: Do you want to remove a specific notification or all other notifications of your app from notification centre

Comment: @Chetan I would like to remove all other notifications that came from my app.

Comment: You are trying to remove the notifications  in background or foreground

Comment: @Chetan In the background. Is this not something iOS allows? If not is there a workaround?

Comment: I have a solution which I used and is working fine. This is to to store the previous notification , and if you want to show new notification remove the previous one and show new one. I can give this code if you want. its in objective C

Comment: @Chetan Yes please, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below are methods to save and remove the notificaiton
NoticationName Is just any name so as to recognise the notification to be removed

```
 #pragma mark - Remove Notification

    - (void) removedStoredLocalNotificationAndCancelNotificationFromPanelOfType: (NSString*) notificationName
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        id storedObject = [defaults objectForKey: notificationName];

        if([storedObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
        {
            UILocalNotification* removeNotification = (UILocalNotification*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)[defaults objectForKey:notificationType]];

            if(removeNotification)
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:removeNotification];
                [defaults removeObjectForKey: notificationName];
            }
            removeNotification = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [defaults removeObjectForKey: notificationName];
        }


        defaults = nil;

    }

    #pragma mark -Save notification
    - (void) saveNewLocalNotificationInUserDefaultsOfType: (NSString*) notificationName withLocalNotification: (UILocalNotification*)localNotification
    {

        //************* Check if previous Notification is Present. If YES remove it and show new notification with storing new data in userDefaults**************//
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if(![defaults objectForKey:notificationName])
        {
            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];
            [defaults setObject:data forKey:notificationName];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }
        else if ([defaults objectForKey:notificationName])
        {

            // Remove previous notification
            //Check if any observation notification is present.If YES remove it from user defaults if stored and cancel local notification

            [self removedStoredLocalNotificationAndCancelNotificationFromPanelOfType:notificationName];

            //Store new notification

            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];
            [defaults setObject:data forKey:notificationName];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately this also did not remove the notifications from the notification centre. It seems like the notifications are not making it into the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications` array in the first place which may be why none of these snippets are working to remove them. I don't understand what would cause this to happen though, as I am scheduling the notifications through `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification`, which is standard procedure in iOS.

Comment: can you share the code if possible. If, I can look into it.